# libmwlaunchermain.so not found

Tags: matlab, shared-library

Hi I have been searching on internet and tried to export the path of these libraries, but still I am getting an error.

Location of the `libmwlaunchermain.so` in my Ubuntu system is: `"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64"`.

What could be the possible solution? I need these files to run .exe file generated using `deploytool`.

Comment: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64 not in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? ....  ? Have you tried $ `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [name of executable]`

Answer (score 3):

It was an error, while running executable file, I was passing the whole path for library `"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64"` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was then `"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/bin/glnxa64"`.

I changed it to MATLAB location `"/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a"`.

Its working now.

Comment: What did you change to `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a`? `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?